# How can I detect if C# compiler (Roslyn) is running to get IDE diagnostics on VSCode instead of explicit dotnet building?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, msbuild, roslyn, csproj

Is there a `csproj` target or property that I can use to differentiate the automatic compilation that Roslyn LSP runs to give me diagnostics on VSCode from actual explicit build compilation?

I need to have different `csproj` elements when running on IDE vs when building. But I don't want to change the build (e.g. by adding extra MSBuild properties via command-line).

Is there some MSBuild target like a "pre-lint" or a property like a "IDE=true" which is already automatically added/called by Roslyn or Omnisharp only when linting on the IDE (i.e. when getting errors/warnings squiggles automatically when typing, not when running a build task)?

Comment: There is some MSBuild properties that can be used to distinguish, but since you mentioned analyzers there's some caveats to even getting to that. That said, you can you offer a bit more insight into why you are needing different behaviors here? This feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and you might be on the right track but also might be going the wrong way.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski I was basically trying to workaround a bug in the VSCode C# extension where it doesn't recognize generated sources properly, which gives me errors in the IDE (but not when building). Explicitly including the generated sources as compile input solves it, but I'd have to do that conditionally, so it works both in IDE and when building. Turns out I was able to use a setting so it uses Omnisharp instead of Roslyn (which doesn't have that bug). Still it's an interesting question I think, and it could be useful in general to be able to do that for other potential use cases.

Comment: There is no "pre-lint" or "lint" target. In the "build", the analyzers are run are part of the [`csc` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/csc-task?view=vs-2022) which invokes the C# compiler. Although it may be reading the project file, the editor is not running MSBuild to produce the "errors/warnings squiggles".

Comment: Are you saying that you have auto-generated source files that you don't compile? Is that correct? If you explicitly add the files to the project as items in the `none` item group, instead of the `compile` item group, does that resolve the issue?

Comment: @JonathanDodds It's [this bug](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-csharp-vscode/issues/57#issuecomment-1666004725) - that's when C# extension updated and switched to Roslyn. I was including the files from Godot's source generators explicitly in `<Compile>` so I could workaround the bug in the IDE (and get no error squiggles for the missing references); and I wanted to do that except when building (otherwise I'd get duplicate definitions). But then I found out that I could just change it back to Omnisharp to solve the issue. I'll see if I can test with `<None>` later, if I have time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Godot. Is the generated code using the `[GeneratedCode]` attribute?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Using `<None>` didn't help. Btw, I'm also using .NET 7 regex generator now. For comparison, the files generated by Godot (v4.1.1) have neither `GeneratedCodeAttribute` nor `// <auto-generated/>`. The files also end in `.generated.cs` instead of `.g.cs`. This is different from the regex generator. However, neither Godot partial defs nor `GeneratedRegexAttribute` partial defs are recognized on Roslyn. They only work through Omnisharp.

Comment: Yeah, we need to just fix the bug properly here; I'm hoping to look at this in the next week or two.